# How to align a Div in a table cell- Not working for me

Tags: html, css

I have a table which I want to align some divs horizontally, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I'm sure the solution in simple.. What I'm finding annoying is that the `text-align` feature is only aligning the textareas (which is perfectly normal) but I can't find a way to do the same with the divs.

What is weird though is that when I zoom in a lot it does align.

[jsFiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/Macint0sh_Plus/f9phr566/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/9a2mc3vw/ ~ check this fiddle

```
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/sn7XtQE.jpg');
  height: 51px;
  width: 51px;
  display: table-cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will work if you delete **display: inline-block** in your div **id**

```
background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/sn7XtQE.jpg');
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin: 0 auto;
```